# PHP Export Array with key to CSV through Submit Button

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am trying to Export array with key to CSV through $_SESSION.
But the csv exported return empty. I tried to var_dump the array before exporting, the array value is there but it cannot show on .csv file.

```
$csvdata = array();
$data2 = array('number'=>10, 'marks'=>20);
array_push($csvdata, $data2);

$ser_arr = serialize($csvdata);
$_SESSION['ses_arr'] = $ser_arr;


<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" name="upload_excel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" name="Export" value="export"/>            
</form>
```

So when the user click on "Export" button, it will retrieve the array from $_SESSION and output to .csv. But currently the output shows empty. Can somebody help me with this?

```
if(isset($_POST["Export"])){
  $realdata = unserialize($_SESSION['ses_arr']);

  header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv'); 

  ob_end_clean();
  $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
  fputcsv($output, array(reset($realdata))); 

  foreach ($realdata as $row) {
      fputcsv($output, $row);
  }

  exit();
  fclose($output);  
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
 fputcsv($output, array(reset($realdata)));
```

to add records to the csv file. But the

```
reset($realdata)
```

itself gives the following array

```
Array
(
[number] => 10
[marks] => 20
)
```

which is enough to be passed inside fputcsv. As you are wrapping it inside another array gives you the error. So change the line as follows and it will work

```
fputcsv($output, reset($realdata));
```

Finally, the complete working code looks as follows

```
<?php
$csvdata = array();
$data2 = array('number'=>10, 'marks'=>20);
array_push($csvdata, $data2);

$ser_arr = serialize($csvdata);
$_SESSION['ses_arr'] = $ser_arr;

if(isset($_POST["Export"])){
   $realdata = unserialize($_SESSION['ses_arr']);
   header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv'); 

   ob_end_clean();
   $output = fopen("php://output", "w");

   fputcsv($output, reset($realdata)); 

   foreach ($realdata as $row) {
      fputcsv($output, $row);
   }

   exit();
   fclose($output);  
} 
?>


<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" name="upload_excel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" name="Export" value="export"/>            
</form>
```

and the output looks as follows. The duplication is in your code itself, I believe you know that.

```
10,20
10,20
```

Comment: Hi, the .csv output is still empty with the above changes.
Here is the unserialize array
fputcsv($output, reset($realdata));
array(2) { ["number"]=> int(10) ["marks"]=> int(20) } 
array(2) { ["number"]=> int(10) ["marks"]=> int(20) }  
is it something wrong with the passing of array?

Comment: Let me add the complete working code from me to the above answer